# According to CMOS, can I change plural words in a quotation to singular, and vice versa?

Tags: grammar, quotes, chicago-manual-of-style, rules

Consider, for example, that the following sentence is from an external source and that I desire to quote it in my own work (please pay attention to the structure of the sentence, not its ambiguous or odd content):

> A and B originate from X in a peculiar way and nobody regards them as Y.

In light of the rules of the Chicago Manual of Style, is it permissible to quote the text in the first way (see below), or must I do it the second way?

1. According to my source, A "originate[s] from X in a peculiar way and nobody regards [it] as Y."
2. According to my source, A originates "from X in a peculiar way and nobody regards" it "as Y."

[This source suggests that the things that I wish to do are permissible in MLA style](https://depts.washington.edu/engl/askbetty/changing_quotations.php), and I wonder if the same is permissible in Chicago style.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant portion of the *Chicago Manual of Style* is available online here:
https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/16/ch13/ch13_toc.html

While it is a pay-resource, they do offer 30-day free trials, so it should be possible to get the definitive answer at no cost, if that's what you want to do.

If you are going to be using it frequently, it's currently available at only $2.99 in Kindle on Amazon ($35 for a print version).

Comment: I found that CMOS 13.12 slightly answers my question. I don't think that the answer is sufficient, but I'll award the 100 reputation because you pointed me to an overview that allowed me to find at least something.

Comment: Is it possible to provide some related quote from the referenced source in the answer?

Answer (score -2):

That is not a quote.
You can rephrase it that way but do not use the quote marks.
Just say: A originates from X in a peculIar way but nobody regards (what is it? A or X?)  as Y.

Comment: It may be permissible to paraphrase it like that but the reader will wonder what parts are quoted and whether I'm interpreting or even misrepresenting my source because a lack of quotes is a lack of distinction between my words and those of the person that I'm quoting. I often still need to quote with quotation marks, so I need to know what's permissible when I do use quotes.